# In Blogger, using linkwithin with specific posts

Tags: blogger, label

I want to show the LinkWithin widget only for a label type in the entry page (item).

I tried this code to accomplish it, but it does not work.

```
<b:widget id='HTML7' locked='false' title='LinkWithin' type='HTML'>
    <b:includable id='main'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
            <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                <b:if cond='label.name == "films"'>
                    <data:content/>
                </b:if>
            </b:loop>
        </b:if>
    </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get? What do you see?

Comment: If I use only the blog.pageType condition it works fine, but when I add the label.name condition does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER (Second Try):**

The previous answer was using widgets and when we do loop of labels there, we get all available labels of the blog but we want what the post is having.

So I moved the code to different location in the template and now it seems to work as it should.

Find the `<data:postLabelsLabel/>` in the template (80% down in my template) and after the closing `</div>` that contains this tag copy the following code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
   <ul>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
      <b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Películas&quot;'>
        <li>
          <data:content/>
        </li>
      </b:if>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:if>
```

Again you need to replace `<data:content/>` with the HTML content that you find in **Dashboard > Layout > LinksWithin Gadget**.

You can also delete that LinksWithin from the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code between the asterisks

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
**<b:if cond='data:label.isLast'>**
   <b:if cond='label.name == "films"'>
     <data:content/>
   </b:if>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
```

I got mine working.